Authorize(Roles = ...) not working on ASP.NET Core 6 microservice
I am trying to use the Authorize attribute to validate a user's roles, but it never actually checks the role (any call with any role will go through successfully). Here, I just put in a check for a role named Temp, which is not on the token I'm testing with, which is also confirmed by the code below also reading out the roles from the claims itself.
In my Program.cs, I have AddAuthentication(), AddMvc() (calls AddAuthentication()), UseAuthentication(), and UseAuthorization() called in that order, which I understand to be correct. I don't think I need any custom authorization handler, since checking roles should be pretty standard...
I don't do any additional setup, like for policies, since I'm not using policies and I'm only checking by roles.
I don't have [AllowAnonymous] on my controller definition.
What else could I be missing here?
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("temp")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Temp")]
    public ActionResult Temp()
    {
        var roles = this.IdentityService.GetRoles();
        return this.Content(string.Join(",", roles));
    }

    public List<string> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = new List<string>();

        if (this.context.HttpContext != null &&
            this.context.HttpContext.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "roles"))
        {
            roles.AddRange(this.context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "roles").Select(c => c.Value));
        }

        return roles;
    }


It seems like you are using token in a mvc project. Do you have other authentication scheme? Could you post all codes related to AddAuthentication()....? By the way It should be c=>c.Type==ClaimTypes.Role

It doesn't work if I use ClaimTypes.Roles since that resolves to http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role. Could this be related to my problem?

I don't have anything special in AddAuthentication(), just that call only.

I ended up just using a custom claims validator found in this post: How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?
